# How to display openstreetmap marker information when click the marker icon

Tags: android, openstreetmap, marker, osmdroid

I'm trying to display a openstreetmap marker information. But doesn't show the marker information.

How can I?

Here is the my code:

```
private void addMarker(GeoPoint center) {
        Marker marker = new Marker(mapView);
        marker.setPosition(center);
        marker.setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, Marker.ANCHOR_BOTTOM);
        marker.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.google_marker1));
        marker.setTitle("City");
        marker.setSubDescription(hMap.get(Constants.CITY).trim());

        marker.setOnMarkerClickListener(new Marker.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker, MapView mapView) {
                marker.showInfoWindow();
                return true;
            }
        });

        mapView.getOverlays().clear();
        mapView.getOverlays().add(marker);
        mapView.invalidate();
    }
```

Comment: The code looks ok for me. it is similar to the [official demo code](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/OpenStreetMapViewer/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/samplefragments/SampleOsmPath.java) except that the demo has no ` marker.setOnMarkerClickListener(...)` of its own. Where does the Marker-class come from? osmdroid-5.2, osmbonuspack, own implementation? does you app has a resource R.layout.bonuspack_bubble wich defines the popup-layout? `does not show`means the marker icon is visible. what happens if you debug `onMarkerClick`?

Comment: Thank you for your responds. osmdroid-4.2, osmbonuspack-v4.8. I haven't a resource R.layout.bonuspack_buble. The marker was displayed. But when I click the marker icon, doesn't display the marker information.

Comment: Have you tried using osmdroid-5.2 (either without osmbonuspack or to newest verion of osmbonuspack)? since 5.2. the Marker class has moved from osmbonuspack to osmdroid to make shure that both match each other it contains the required R.layout.bonuspack_buble needed to display the popup. if you have to stick to the old version try adding bonuspack_buble from https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/osmdroid-android/src/main/res/layout/bonuspack_bubble.xml